# Docker compose - can't find manage.py file

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I want to create with docker-compose 2 Docker containers. 1 for DB (Mongo) and 1 for web (Django).
Here are my files

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    command: mongod
  web:
    build: code/
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**code/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY cleverInvestWeb/ /code/
```

In the directory **code/cleverInvestWeb/** is my manage.py file from django.

when i run `docker-compose up` it throws me the following error:

```
web_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When i start the container via Docker itself with `docker exec -it dockerdiplom_web bash` and do an `ls` there it shows the `manage.py` file.

Do you have an idea why docker-compose doesn't find my file when starting?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `volumes:`?  If you `docker-compose run web sh` with and without that declaration, what do you see inside the running containers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The directory structure in your Dockerfile and docker-compose seems confusing. Another thing that is strange is you are able to see to file after `docker exec`.

You copy your code to `COPY cleverInvestWeb/ /code/` in Dockerfile, and then mount the volume in Docker-compose to `.:/code` so everything will be overide in the existing image on `/code` location.

I assume your python file place inside local directory `cleverInvestWeb` so docker-compose boot up it will override the existing image code and your file update location will be `code/cleverInvestWeb/manage.py` or `/code/manage.py`

To debug:

- remove mounting in docker-compose and check if it works
- `command: tail -f /dev/null` set this command in docker-compose and verify your file location using `docker exec`

Comment: @David Maze comment and your answer were helpful. I removed the `volumes`section in my docker-compose.yml file and corrected the `command` with `python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. Thank you guys it works now! :D

Answer (score 2):

*This is a common error among the Django beginners*

The docker file '**docker-compose.yml**' configuration (shown at the beginning of this request) is alrigh... Except for the django project folder missing when calling the **manage.py** file!

The Line should have been:

command: `python nameOfDjangoFolder/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Explaination about Volumes named "**/code**"
The Volume "**/code**" is building your application using the root of the Docker project folder:

`/home/user/Documents/youDockerProjectFolder` = (Code)

Inside the "`/home/user/Documents/youDockerProjectFolder`" you should find the Django project folder: `yourDjangoProjectFolder/`

Inside that folder you will find the manage.py... So it's normal to have to use ***`yourDjangoProjectFolder/manage.py`*** in order to call manage.py

MORE but not important for this solution
Inside the Docker Project Folder another important file is found
`yourDjangoProjectFolder/youDjangoProjectFolder/settings.py`

Answer (score 1):

change your command to

```
command: python code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: same problem
`web_1  | python: can't open file 'code/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem while deploying to Digital ocean from github repo using Dockerfile. For my case I had accidentally added `manage.py` to `.gitignore` file. So, the my github repo never the had the `manage.py` file.

You should ensure that `manage.py` file is actually present in its expected directory.